# Heating issue in Asus Zenbook 14

Tags: 16.04, asus

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my new Asus Zenbook 14. The machine is overheating, I am doubtful if the fans are running. Any leads are appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 is in it's final days of supported life so you're wasting resources trying to fix it unless you're planning to use ESM](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/)  Why not try a supported release that has life left.

Comment: Especially in this case using a release **5 years older** than the hardware is really a wrong move. You need the very latest release if it comes with a 11th generation Intel CPU and even that might not have the proper support.

Comment: Make sure your sensors are detected by running `sudo sensors-detect` and answering yes to the prompts.

Comment: I have updated to Ubuntu 20.04 and the issue seems to subside.